# Small-size speech recognition on Android to look for keywords

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I'm developing a voice command app and need to use speech to text in Android.
I want my app to work offline. Its yet possible only in jellybean version and it requires huge sized database to download and keep in the device. But i don't require whole database, i just want few keywords for the conversions.

Is it possible to record a .wav files on our own and set its reference to a particular word and when a voice input is given we could match the two voice tracks and recognize the corresponding word accordingly. So basically i want to make my own speech to text dictionary database? If yes then how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Pocketsphinx on Android:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

It allows you to look for keywords. Database size is about 5mb now, but if you limit keywords it can be reduced to about 500kb. You can learn more about CMUSphinx from website

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Since your developing for Android, why don't you just use Androids base voice recognition software as your own. (Unless it's to be paid app)

Creating .wav files yourself will prove difficult for usage from people outside your vocal culture range, meaning e.g. Someone with a different accent won't be able to use it.

So access googles libaries for voice recognition.

Comment: yeah but for using google libraries either i need to be online or need to download complete offline speech to text database(which is very huge in size). so i want to develop my own small library which can include only required words for my app. is this possible?